# Does casting Dispel Magic on the Illusion created by a Mislead spell also end the Mislead's invisibility?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, illusion, invisibility

The Mislead spell has two effects: It creates an illusory copy of the caster that lasts for the duration (concentration, up to 1 hour), and it makes the caster invisible (same conditions as the Invisibility spell). Now, it should be possible to make the illusory double go away by successfully casting Dispel Magic at it. My question is: Does such a Dispel also end the invisibility on the caster, if it's still active?

Comment: Related: [Does Dispel Magic end the spell for everyone affected or just the target?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99631/23547), [Can a single casting of Dispel Magic dispel every creature conjured by a Conjure Animals spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90140/23547)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The invisibility will end with the Mislead spell

Dispel Magic says:

> **Any spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target **ends**.

Dispel Magic does not dispel the spell effect, it *ends the spell*. All effects caused by the spell end with the spell. If you target and dispel the illusion that is created on *Misleads* target, you dispel the *Mislead* spell, and with that the invisibility.

Mislead is a single target spell, targeting only the caster. The illusionary double is an effect created "on" that caster, even while it is independent of the invisibility. This is different from a situation where a spell like *bless* has multiple targets: in those cases, the spell only would end for one of the targets — which is not evident from Dispel Magic's text, but has been stated in Sage Advice Compendium.

Comment: This line of thinking would contradict Sage Advice's ruling on targeting one summoned creature... where it states that only that target is ended not the entire spell, would it not?

Comment: @Slagmoth My perspective is that because Mislead has a single target, the the illusion is an effect created "on" that target, not a separate, independent thing. Maybe I did not express that clearly enough.

Comment: The target *dispel magic* refers to is the target of *dispel magic*, not the target of the original spell. In this case the magical effect is the illusory double, not the caster of *mislead*

Comment: Also in a lot of other magic dispelling areas of effect, the entire magic ends even if only a portion of the spell's aoe overlaps with the spell-ending aoe. (e.g., [Darkness](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Darkness))

Comment: I expand my previous comment because I am surprised about the consensus of this answer. The text of *Dispel Magic* says "Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends." The caster is targeting the illusory double, hence the **magical effect** and not the **creature** that have cast *Mislead*: the target is the double, not the caster of Mislead. The spells ends for the target of *Dispel Magic*, not of *Mislead*.

Comment: @Eddymage I think the disagreement arises because the meaning of "any spell on the target ends" is not clear.  Does it mean 'Any source spell that has been cast on the target of the dispel ends, and thus all of its effects on other targets end as well', or does it mean "the _effects_ of any spell on that particular target of dispel end, even though the source spell itself does not'?  Based on just the spell description, I would say the former.  It is only with the SAC clarification that I would confidently state the latter (as I did in my answer).

Comment: @Eddymage Also note the line in dispel magic, "On a successful check, the spell ends." which does not even mention the target.  That's not helpful, either.

Comment: Of note: IIRC, the 5e rules do not consistently distinguish between "spell" and "spell effect" when talking about an ongoing spell.

Comment: The problem seems to be, does "ends the spell" mean ending the *whole* spell, as a literal reading would suggest, or does it mean "ends the targeted magical/spell effect" only, as Sage Advice seems to suggest?

Comment: @Kirt The natural reading is that the spell ends on the target.

Answer (score 16):

### No; the result depends on what the caster targets

*Mislead* is a spell with a single target - you (its range is 'Self').  However, once cast, it produces **two separate and distinct** magical effects:

> You become invisible at the same time that an illusory double of you appears where you are standing.

The first effect is that you become invisible, while the second is that an illusory double of you appears.

The caster of *Dispel Magic* has as their choice a number of different targets:

> Choose one creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

The caster of *Dispel Magic* could choose as their target you (one creature), or the invisibility on you (one magical effect), or the illusory duplicate of you (another magical effect).

If they choose *you*, then they may:

> end the effects of a spell on the target

If the spell ends on you, the target of *Mislead*, then all of its effects on you end - both the invisibility *and* the duplicate.

However, they might choose as the target of their *dispel magic* one of the magical effects of *Mislead*.  In this case they will dispel only the one magical effect chosen, but not both and not the entire spell.  In this case *dispel magic* doesn't end the *Mislead* spell itself.  Rather, it ends all effects of the spell *on the target chosen*.  If the target is you, then all effects of the spell is indeed the spell itself.  But if the target of *dispel magic* is just one of the magical effects of *mislead*, then only the effects of the *mislead* spell on that one target (the magical effect) are ended.

This is not obvious from the text of the *dispel magic* spell itself ("the spell ends").  However, it was clarified in the [June 2016 Rules Answers article](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-june-2016), later included on page 14 of the [2016 Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=14), and can also be found on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA183):

> **If dispel magic targets the magical effect from bless cast by a cleric, does it remove the effect on all the targets?**
> Dispel magic ends a spell on one target. It doesn’t end the same spell on other targets.

In other words, if three creatures are all under the effects of the same *bless* spell, and I cast *dispel magic* on one of them, it ends only the effects of the *bless* on one of them - it doesn't actually end the 'source spell' that is affecting all of them.  Similarly, casting *dispel magic* on just the illusory copy of you will end all effects of *mislead* on that illusory copy, but it won't end the original *mislead* spell itself or other effects of the spell on other targets, like the invisibility on you.

### Targeting Strategy

If I am being bothered by something I suspect of being a misleading duplicate of you, what should I choose as my target?  That depends on whether I know where you are.  Note that I don't have to see you to choose you (a creature) as my target - you just have to be in range and not behind total cover.  Also note that even if you are invisible, I still know where you are unless you are Hidden.  If I am confident that I can successfully choose you as a target for *dispel magic*, doing so will end both your invisibility and the existence of the duplicate (even if it is not in range).

If, however, I can see only the duplicate, and I am not sure of where you are - or even whether you are actually within range - then it is safer for me to cast *dispel magic* on the duplicate.  Doing so won't end your invisibility, but it is better than casting my spell and having it fail due to having an illegitimate target.

Answer (score 1):

### No, the spell treats the invisibility and the double as separate magical effects.

The spell notes that if the invisibility portion of it is broken, the double is unaffected.

> The double lasts for the duration, but the invisibility ends if you attack or cast a spell.

This suggests that the double and the invisibility are **separate** magical effects.

Dispel Magic targets

> one creature, object, or magical effect within range

So you can target the double, but that casting of *Dispel Magic* only targets that magical effect (the illusory double), not the creature that cast the spell. It would dispel that spell on that target (and any others that are on the illusory double as well)

You could also target the invisible caster of the spell, but again that only influences the caster so that the invisibility portion would be dispelled, as well as any spells on the caster, but the illusory double would remain unaffected.

Comment: You're probably right about targeting the illusion, but wouldn't targeting the caster target the whole spell, and as such, end the whole thing? Is it possible to target just the invisibility on the caster, instead of the creature that is the caster, and does that make a difference?

Comment: For the only targetting the invisibility, not the caster. I guess so, and that would only dispel the invisibility and not other magical effects on the caster (like for example if someone cast death ward on the caster). But this is probably a different question altogether.

Comment: I think the other part of the question is well addressed in Kirt's answer. As Sage Advice Compendium says dispelling the same spell on one target doesn't automatically dispel it on all other targets affected by that spell.

Comment: If you target the invisible caster of the spell and your *Dispel Magic* succeeds, then the spell on the target _ends_, meaning that the duration expires and the double disappears, by the very description of the spell.